# How can I create typings to describe this common library pattern (callable namespace)?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write TypeScript typings for an existing Javascript library.  The library is packaged as CJS, and exports several variables and functions at the top level.  It also exports a single top level "namespace like" object with the same variables and functions.  (I know this is not a "recommended" pattern; I'm not here to discuss that.)

All of these are valid in an ESM (.mjs) context:

```js
// Default export
import lib from "lib";
const x = lib(...);
const y = lib.b(...);

// Top level function, namespace-like variable
import {b, lib} from "lib";
const x = lib(...);
const y = b(...);
```

I want to write typings that describe this pattern.  I can write top-level exports like

```
export function b(...);
declare function lib(...);
export default lib;
```

but I don't see an easy way to create a namespace that re-uses the various top level exports, so I can't really merge the function declaration with a namespace declaration.

Likewise, I can wrap the other functions in a namespace to start with

```
export namespace lib {
  function b(...);
}
```

but I don't see how to re-export `lib.b` at the top level, as simply `b`.

I've tried putting the top level exports in their own file ("top-exports.d.ts"), which lets me write

```
export * from "./top-exports"; 
import * as lib from "./top-exports";
export { lib }
```

but then I can't make `lib` callable.  I know that you can use "export assignment" to make a callable default (`export = lib`), but then I'm back to the problem of making a callable, namespace-like object with both top-level and namespace-wrapped exports in the same place.

Comment: Re: your ESM example: AFAIK, it's invalid to declare a variable using the identifier `b` after it's already been used in an import declaration. You should be seeing TS Error 2440 in that case.

Comment: Oh good catch, thanks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand a requirement, I think this is what you're looking for:

`lib.d.ts`

```ts
type A = () => string;
type B = () => number;

declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;
// ...etc.

interface Lib {
  (): void;
  a: A;
  b: B;
  // ...etc.
}

declare const lib: Lib;

declare namespace lib {
  export type Num = number;
}

export {
  lib as default,
  a,
  b,
  lib,
  // ...etc.
};
```

`module.ts`

```ts
import {a, lib} from './lib';

const x = a();
const y = lib();
const z = lib.b();
const n: lib.Num = 42;
```

Comment: Your example has more repetition than mine.  Suppose that instead of `const a: A`, I have `const aVeryLongName: SomeGeneric<WithSeven, Very<Complex>, TypeParams...>` -- that has to be re-declared inside `interface Lib` verbatim, and if you want JSDoc to be picked up then that has to be duplicated too.

Comment: I don't see a requirement about repetition in your question. Perhaps you can update your question to reflect all of the specific requirements.

Comment: I mean, it's not a specific *requirement* for this, just generally a good coding practice.  I should have said, your example does not follow "DRY" principles, and thus scales poorly for large projects.

Comment: I guess I just fail to see the repetition. The types are defined only once and then reused on the interface members and top-level declarations. (Also, [this works with `esModuleInterop` set to `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740647/how-can-i-create-typings-to-describe-this-common-library-pattern-callable-names/69741311?noredirect=1#comment123275502_69741016)).

Comment: It's hard to explain in a comment, so I made [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/library-typing-example-90kcm). Compare "verbose-lib.d.ts" with the combination of "lib.d.ts" and "top-export.d.ts" to see how your way results in serious duplication.  (Of course, I still haven't addressed the `esModuleInterop` issue!)

Comment: Unlike in my example, in that sandbox, you've not defined the types separately from the declarations, so that's contributing heavily to the duplication. In regard to JSDoc, I don't know enough about how TS processes it to give a reply. I agree that keeping things as DRY as possible is great, but I just don't see a way to improve that here and meet your requirements. Feel free to suggest!

Comment: I see now that you're using `declare const` instead of `declare function`, which allows you to reuse the signatures.  I typically use `function` where possible so I haven't educated myself on the difference (if any).  That might be concise enough for me to try your approach, thanks.

Comment: How'd that work? I was also thinking that if you're opposed to separately named types for some reason, that for the top-level exports, you can always define them as functions, and then reference their types in your interface using `typeof myFunction`.

Comment: I wound up doing basically what you suggested.  I declared all the constants, functions, and types in the namespace, then re-exported them at top level with `export const myFunc: typeof lib.myFunc` or `export interface SomeInterface extends lib.SomeInterface {}` -- saves a line or two per export, and seems to work well with VSCode's JSDoc parsing.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing about the JSDoc results!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that sort of works.  `export = lib` is required if you want a a function merged with a namespace.  The problem is that you cannot `export * from` a module that was created using export assignment (`export =`), so you have to re-export each item by hand:

```
// top-exports.d.ts
declare namespace lib {
  function a(...);
  type SomeType = ...;
  // etc
}
declare function lib(...);

export = lib;



// lib.d.ts
import * as lib from "./top-exports";
import {a, b, c, d, SomeType, OtherType} from "./top-exports";

export default lib;
export {lib, a, b, c, d};
export type {SomeType, OtherType};
```

Of course this is much harder to maintain, spreading definitions across two files, and having to remember to include any new stuff in two extra places (the `import {...}` and `export {...}` statements), but at least you don't have to declare anything twice.  I'd still really love to see a better answer.

Comment: Crud.  This works exactly as I want it to when `esModuleInterop` is set to `false`, but with the flag set to `true`, the merged namespace-slash-function is no longer callable -- `import {lib} from "lib"; const x = new lib(...)` fails.  Back to the drawing board.